# Twitch Api - Password grant not permitted

Tags: java, api, apache-httpclient-4.x

I wanted to access the twitch api,with the following code.

```
package droa.app.twitch;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

public class Notifier {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws URISyntaxException 
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws ClientProtocolException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token");
        org.apache.http.client.HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", Credentials.clientid));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", Credentials.clientsecret));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", Credentials.username));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", Credentials.password));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("scope", "user_read"));
        request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(request);    

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            }


    }

}
```

but it dosn't seem to work, i get an Error.

> {"status":403,"message":"Password grant not permitted for client ID
>   chodustnuqjzkc07ohd3rfkbzrlopzb","error":"Forbidden"}

i followed the offical guide at https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/password-credentials.md

i was wondering, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been trying to do the exact same thing. If you dont use JavaScript it looks to be impossible! I would try curl-java: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/java/
I can't get it working, but you might!

But looking at your response, I would gather that your client on Twitch some how cannot use a password grant flow. If so, this is why my java application isnt working aswell. I would be so annoyed if the API will reject users password grant flow... especially since no one told me!

"Due to the sensitive nature of handling user passwords, this type of authorization flow is only permitted on a case-by-case basis. If you think your application is a good candidate, please contact us directly."
-STRAIGHT from their page! All this time we were doing it right! I will contact them on my behalf, (I spent about a month on this issue alone).

Comment: i changed the entire thing to run a browser script instead, that returned the token that way.. it seems to work alot better with php or javascript, then java.. i don't know why really, but dosn't matter anymore, thanks for the response, even thoughit got in late :)